# Optimizacion o refactorizacion de funcion Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, refactoring

Estoy trabajando con la siguiente estructura de HTML:

```
      <li class="item">
        <a class="item-content" href="#"
          ><i class="item-icon fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span>Ubicaciones</span
          ><i class="down fas fa-sort-down"></i
        ></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion1</li>
          <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion2</li>
          <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion3</li>
          <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion1</li>
          <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion2</li>
          <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

La cual es un  sidebar como el de la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acabo de empezar a trabajar por el lado del frontend, comunmente trabajo por lado del backend. Queria saber si mi funcion de javascript para desplegar los sub menu del sidebar puede mejorar y hacerce mas limpia.

Esta es la funcion de javascript que tengo actualmente:

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')
  
  items.forEach(item =>{
    var childrens = Array.from(item.children)
    var itemContent = childrens.find(x => x.classList.contains('item-content'))
    itemContent.addEventListener('click', () =>{
      var down = Array.from(itemContent.children).find(x => x.classList.contains('down'))
            down.classList.toggle('active')
      var subMenu = childrens.find(x => x.classList.contains('sub-menu'))
      subMenu.classList.toggle('active')
    })
 })
```

He trabajado con Jquery, pero en este caso quiero hacerlo solo con js puro

Comment: Si la tiene, me parece que no leiste bien la pregunta

Comment: Lo siento es que de primeras no terminaba de comprenderla. :)

Comment: La pregunta está basada en opiniones y va la mía: No me convence lo que haces con `children` si puedes llegar a los otros elementos directamente: `let itemContent = item.querySelector('.item-content');` y, en el caso del submenú, solo agregas _closest_ para referenciar al padre: `let subMenu = itemContent.closest('li').querySelector('.sub-menu');`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario @Triby, de verdad lo aprecio mucho

Comment: Añado como comentario sobre la primera línea: estás seleccionando de todo tu documento (tu página entera o iframe) toooodos los elementos que tengan la clase item, y que es posible que haya más elementos que sólo los de tu menú, por lo que debes tener precaución al utilizar selectores tan genéricos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ahorrar un par de lineas de JS si añades algo de css extra.

Cuando haces click sobre el elemento padre `.item`, agregas un modificador `.item--active`
y en el css agregas un selector que condicione a que los `.dropdown` sólo sean visibles cuando el padre tenga esa clase.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item')

items.forEach(item =>{
  item.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    item.classList.toggle('item--active')
  })
})
```

```css
li {
  display: block;
}
 
/* Selector que condiciona cuando serán visibles los dropdown */
.item--active > .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
}

/*
De esta forma también puedes desplegar el dropdown sin necesidad de usar JS

.item:hover > .dropdown {
  display: block;
}

*/
```

```html
<li class="item">
  <a class="item-content" href="#">
    <i class="item-icon fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span>Ubicaciones</span>
    <i class="down fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu dropdown">
    <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion1</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion2</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion3</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion1</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion2</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Ubicacion3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="item">
  <a class="item-content" href="#">
    <i class="item-icon fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span>Reportes</span>
    <i class="down fas fa-sort-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="sub-menu dropdown">
    <li class="sub-item">Reportes1</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Reportes2</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Reportes3</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Reportes4</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Reportes5</li>
    <li class="sub-item">Reportes6</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```